# Full drive encryption with Bitlocker freezes at 99.9%

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption

I have enabled Bitlocker for fully encrypting a partition/drive on my disk a few days ago (it took some hours to reach 99.9% completion). This partition only contains a few GB of data (which Windows 10 programs do not need to access).

Ever since, after I shutdown/restart the computer and unlock that drive, the progress bar window shows up again and always stops at 99.9%. Bitlocker lock mechanism seems to be working properly, i.e. I cannot access the drive without the password and only when I unlock it, the progress bar shows up again.

Is this a normal behavior? What are the remaining 0.1% that are left to encrypt? Can I fix this without deactivating Bitlocker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I purchased a refurbished PC for the office that came with a 446GB SSD as the primary disk. I faced the same situation as the OP...the encryption stage would always get to 99.9% completion and go no further. `chkdsk` turned up no disk errors. Resetting the TPM didn't help. Telling BitLocker to use the older encryption algorithm versus the newer didn't help. Encrypting only the used space versus the entire disk made no difference either.

What finally worked was to use the Disk Management tool to shrink the primary partition by some random number of Gigabytes (I chose to shrink off 40GB). I then enabled BitLocker again and this time it ran until the disk was 100% encrypted and it completed successfully. I was then able to go back into the Disk Management tool and enlarge the primary partition to reclaim the 40GB of space I had shrunk off earlier. In the end I had access to the full amount of original disk space and BitLocker was fully enabled.

1. To bring up the Disk Management tool, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then enter `diskmgmt.msc`:

   [image]

   [image]
2. Right-click on the drive you are trying to enable BitLocker on (in my case it was "C:") and choose "Shrink Volume...":

   [image]
3. Tell it how much you want to shrink the volume by (screen not shown here). When finished, the shrunk space will appear as unallocated space to the right of the drive:

   [image]
4. Now return to the BitLocker management window and enable BitLocker again. For me, the encryption now ran to 100% and successfully completed:

   [image]
5. You can now return to the Disk Management tool and reclaim the shrunk space. To do this, right-click on the drive you previously shrunk and select "Extend Volume...":

   [image]
6. Tell it to reclaim all the unallocated space (screen not shown here). When finished, the drive should be back to its original full size, and the entire drive should still be BitLocker protected:

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: Wow! Great investigative work you have done. So basically some loop a Bitlocker function has fails to get the partitions size correctly and shrinking the primary forcibly sets the limit that allows to break that loop... You should get paid by MS for solving them this issue, really!

Comment: TBH in my blitz of research on this problem I ran across a Google link somewhere where the person had done this trick of shrinking the volume to get BitLocker to finish (I don't believe they reclaimed the shrunk space though), so I can't take credit for the solution. I wish I remembered the link so I could give proper attribution. Just wanted to post the solution here though since I'm sure someone else will have need of it.

Answer (score 4):

I just had to do one pause resume cycle with manage-bde on my Windows 10 Pro installation.  I did it in a PowerShell window running as administrator.  The D: drive seemed stuck at 99.9% encrypted.

More specifically, I ran the following:

```
manage-bde -status d:
manage-bde -pause d:
manage-bde -status d:
manage-bde -resume d:
manage-bde -status d:
```

Before pausing, the `manage-bde -status` command output included these lines:

```
    Conversion Status:    Encryption in Progress
    Percentage Encrypted: 99.9%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
```

After pausing, the `manage-bde -status` command output included these lines:

```
    Conversion Status:    Encryption Paused
    Percentage Encrypted: 99.9%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
```

After resuming, the `manage-bde -status` command output included these lines:

```
    Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100.0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection On
```

Also, the old-style Windows Control Panel for BitLocker Drive Encryption changed from saying D: was "BitLocker Encrypting" to saying D: was "BitLocker on":

[image: BitLocker control panel showing BitLocker on]

Comment: Appreciated the detailed update, particularly that `manage-bde` command: great investigation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another Windows 10 computer, plug the disk into that computer (pausing the encryption beforehand) and see if the encryption process completes. If it doesn't after a few hours, assume the encryption is borked. Remove the BitLocker Encryption (if possible) then re-encrypt it on the other system.

If not, then you can either

### Clear your TPM

1. Remove the BitLocker Encryption
2. In your BIOS/UEFI settings, clear/reset the TPM.
3. Reboot your computer.
4. Re-encrypt your drive.
5. If it's still stuck at 99.9%, try the below.

**It is paramount you follow these instructions word-by-word; if you reset the TPM before BitLocker is disabled, You will lose ALL your data!**

#### Reinstall Windows

or

#### Assume that your disk has failed in some way.

Comment: My disk is internal and has been running well for over 9 years... I started using Bitlocker when I upgraded to Win 10 Pro. Why do you believe reinstalling windows will fix this? (any sources?)

Comment: A program on your computer may have irreversibly damaged Windows in some way. I am all too familiar with BitLocker. I bricked my computer just by changing the Hard Disk.

Comment: I doubt the OS is damaged, since when I upgraded to Win 10 I did a clean install (removed completely my previous Windows version) and I started using Bitlocker immediately. It froze at 99.9% and it is still frozen at that percentage... This was almost a couple of years ago.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this. (I'm assuming you have a TPM installed.)

Comment: **If the author clears the TPM before they disable BitLocker they will lose all their data. ** You might want to spend a few minutes and add formatting to your answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Just saw your comment when I finished editing.

Comment: Why are you asking questions, to the author, within the body of your answer?  You should remove the commentary from your answer.  *The author is using Windows 10, not Windows 7.*  Your answer still isn't formatted.  You clearly are attempting to use headings but failed to mark those lines using the appropriate formatting.

Comment: @Ramhound My instructions were assuming Windows 10. I've made that clear now.

Comment: Plugging a BitLocker drive into another system is a horrible idea, considering, the encryption process has not finished.

Comment: And yet the question is still active.

Comment: Disregard my commentary about the user's activity.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me like pausing and unpausing it seemed to give the encryption process a kick once it got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I have a new 1.5 TB Western Digital external hard disk, where I need to Bitlocker encrypt it for first use. It soon went till 99.9% and stuck there.

After Pause, Resume, Pause, Resume three times the pop up closed. Then removing the disk and reinserting it solved the issue. Make sure you don't remove the disk when pop-up for encryption is still open. Let it close, by doing Pause, Resume continuously.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me at 99.9% decryption, and I got stuck:

After Pause, Resume, Pause, Resume three times the pop up closed. Then removing the disk and reinserting it solved the issue. Make sure you don't remove the disk when pop-up for encryption is still open. Let it close, by doing Pause, Resume continuously.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did same and it did work. I was encrypting 16GB USB drive.