# Bitlocker and Resizing Partitions?

Tags: windows, partitioning, bitlocker

I have a 3TB hard drive that I wiped and created a new NTFS partition the full size of the drive and then chose to do a Bitlocker full drive encryption of the more or less empty drive.

I any case after hours of encryption, it got stuck at 99.9%. I found this answer: [Full drive encryption with Bitlocker freezes at 99.9%](https://superuser.com/questions/1121447/full-drive-encryption-with-bitlocker-freezes-at-99-9)

This seemed to help, however, my question is then, what happens to the space that you expanded the partition into?

Why can't I just create a 1GB partition, encrypt that, which would only take a few seconds, then expand that 1GB volume to full size of the drive? How can it still be encrypted?

Comment: According to [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8398dbab-6c80-4c64-a797-7e9f501e742b/bitlocker-extend-volume) when you extend a volume the space it is extended into is encrypted.   (*"Bitlocker does, indeed, appear to automatically detect this and automatically start encrypting the new space that was added."*). It is an old quote though and although from MS employee not official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that. Probably best info out there. I wasn't able to find anything. Well it turns out that two of my 3TB Seagate HDD's were failing which is why they wouldn't fully encrypt. Then I saw Backblaze report showing the older 3TB HDD's had as much as 43% failure rate! I had a spare 4TB that encrypted rather quickly and fully no problem.